# Finding the kernel of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $x_1$ be an element of $W_1$, $x_2$ be an element of $W_2$, and $W_1$ & $W_2$ be subspaces of $V$.

Consider the linear transformation $T$ given by $(x_1,x_2) \mapsto x_1 - x_2$

What is the kernel of this linear transformation?

I know it has to involve $x_1 = x_2$, but what subspace of $V$ does this take place in?

Comment: As a general comment the kernel is a subspace of the source of your map so in this case it is contained in $V \times V$ not $V$

Answer (score 0):

If $x_1 = x_2$ then what can you say about $x_1$ and $W_2$?

Comment: x1 must be an element of W1 and W2, no?

I was thinking W1 intersection W2, but I thought this might include extraneous information.

Comment: You are definitely on the right track with the idea of the intersection but as I said in the other comment the kernel isn't in $V$ but in $V \times V$ (this is where your condition that $x_1 = x_2$ will come into play as well)